# Why do we only sometimes use the definite article when there's a prepositional phrase coming after that defines the noun?

Tags: articles

I've read that when a prepositional phrase comes after a noun, defining it, the noun should take the definite article:

*She was given the responsibility of taking care of her sister.*

*I have the advantage of being a year older.*

However, it seems that this depends on the noun in question. The indefinite article is much preferred in the examples below, right?

*She has a habit of leaving things around the house.*

*We have a tradition of celebrating it on the first Monday of the month.*

Can anyone direct me to some grammar rules regarding this? If there are any.

Comment: OR *She was [given responsibility **for** taking care of](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+given+responsibility+for+taking+care+of%22) her sister*, with no article. So maybe it depends on the preposition itself, as well as the noun. But note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=developed+the+habit+of%2Cdeveloped+a+habit+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), showing that *developed **the** habit of...* is in fact somewhat more common in published writing than *developed **a** habit of...*

Comment: Yea, I agree about the preposition mattering too. I'm enjoying these Ngram things. Would've thought "a habit of" was way more popular.

Comment: I must admit that was my first thought too - but maybe I was influenced by having already read *The indefinite article is much preferred in the examples below* before actually considering your examples. I will admit I was a bit mischievous with my NGram though - I already expected that result because [I deliberately chose to switch](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+the+habit+of%2Chad+a+habit+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) from your ***having** A habit* to my ***developed** THE habit.* (For your *exact* context, A is indeed more common than THE! :)

Comment: ...just don't ask me how I knew "develop" would be more likely with THE. It's definitely true, both because that's what I expected to find AND because that's what the NGram confirmed. But I've no idea why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why don't you post answers? I mean four long comments....It really takes the wind out of the sails of potential responses.

Comment: I don't think we actually found an answer to be honest. Or, we didn't find any rules at play anyway.

Comment: @Lambie: What Brooh said. My first comment really only added a couple of extra complications to the question, and the others just demonstrate what we should all know - just because native speakers have a strong position regarding what are and aren't "natural, idiomatic" usages doesn't imply we always know ***why***.

Comment: Re FumbleFingers comment. Agreed. It isn't just the noun. Zero-article here is grammatical when **of** is changed to **for**.  "She was given responsibility for taking care of her sister."  There the abstract noun *responsibility* hearkens back to the adjective *responsible* and the collocation *to be responsible **for***.

Comment: *The habit* suggests an established habit, something many people do, something well-known to the listener.  I doubt we would prefer the definite article here:  "She has **the** [sic] habit of slapping her thighs and the soles of her shoes like a dancer in lederhosen whenever someone sneezes". https://youtu.be/puE_OYKADYw

Comment: +1 Great question. I've seen textbooks for training ESL teachers that say it's always "the" before a noun modified with "of". My only input is that the feeling is similar to the common difference between "a" and "the", being the nuance that responsibilities and advantages are a *closed set*, so identifying one with "of" is specifying a specific individual, but habits and traditions are not a closed set, so identifying one habit or tradition doesn't mean there aren't other similar habits or traditions. That's as close as I can get. I'm following this question now.

Comment: I think I have a somewhat better theory now: "of"-phrases after nouns can be either *defining* or *non-defining*, similar to *relative clauses*, and it depends on the noun how it's understood. So, the sentence, "*I have the responsibility of watering the lawn*" could be rephrased with a defining relative clause: "*I have the responsibility **which is watering the lawn**.*" In contrast, the sentence, "*I have a habit of forgetting my textbooks at home*" could be rephrased with a non-defining relative clause: "*I have a habit, **which is forgetting my textbooks at home***".

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

1. I have **a** *habit* of biting my nails when I’m nervous.
2. I have **the** *habit of biting my nails* when I’m nervous.

The key in both examples lies in the intent of the sentence. Clearly, the only difference is the choice of article. The rules of grammar that govern the use of articles can be not only prescriptive, but also descriptive. The choice of article, in some circumstances, can be what determines the meaning of the sentence.

In example 1, there is a collection of *habits* in which one (*a*) is *biting my nails*. We can use our understanding of the use of articles to determine that the narrator’s intent is to describe a *habit* among many *habits* (either his own or a more general collection of habits).

In example 2, *the* specific *habit of biting one’s nails* is a habit that exists among a collection of people who have this habit of which I am one. The choice of the definitive article is used to define the entire phrase (*habit of biting my nails*) as specifically important. In this context, the particular habit is one that exists among many people with this habit, not among many habits.

In the context of an example in the question, it’s not quite as neat, but:

> She was given **the** *responsibility of taking care of her sister*.

- She was given **a** *responsibility* to take care of her sister.
- She was given **a** *responsibility* to clean her room.

Answer (score 0):

When what is been written/Spoken about (the noun) is known/definite.
Eg: The boy who came here is my brother.
'The' signals that the noun is definite, that it refers to a particular member of a group

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What you say is true, but I don't see how it answers the question about when to use "a/an" or "the" before a noun modified by a prepositional phrase. How would someone know that "***a habit** of watering the lawn*" and "***the responsibility** of watering the lawn*" are correct grammar while "***a responsibility** of watering the lawn*" is incorrect.